# Hot to debug or capture Next.js network requests with Network Monitor (Firefox/Chrome)

Tags: debugging, networking, python-requests, next.js, capture

Next.js network requests are not captured under Network Monitor (Firefox/Chrome).
I am stuck now for days on finding how to debug or capture Next.js network requests?
The Network Monitor definitely do not capture them.

Reference site: https://de.scalable.capital/broker

Browsers tested: Firefox 88.0 (64-bit), Chrome 90.0.4430.93 (64-Bit)

OS: Linux deb 5.10.0-kali7-amd64

Comment: Requests that happen server-side (in `getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps`) won't be visible on the client (browser).

Comment: I just want to see what client sends and receives to/from server. What happens on server is out of scope.